# Ignoring root json key of nested response class

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, response

I have a class which has user list and team response:

```
public class TeamWithUsersResponse {

    protected List<UserWithSkillsResponse> users;

    private TeamResponse teamResponse;

//constructor and setters/getters
}
```

When I return this class from a controller, json response I get looks like this:

```
{
"users": [],
"teamResponse": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Team"
}
}
```

I would like to ask, how should I remove *teamResponse* key and move *id* and *name* one level up?

P.S.
Before *TeamWithUsersResponse* was extending *TeamResponse*, but I decided that composition is a much better strategy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Jackson's [`@JsonUnwrapped`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0.pr4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) annotation, e.g.:

```
@JsonUnwrapped
private TeamResponse teamResponse;
```